# I can't get the GK authentication dialog to come up

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication, game-center, gamekit

I am really struggling with game center right now. It could be because GK as a whole has been pooping out all day (letterpress was just released!), but I can't get an auth dialog to come up:

```
- (void) authenticateLocalPlayer
{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error)      {
    if (viewController) {
        NSLog(@"Foo 1");
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated) {
        NSLog(@"Foo 2");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Foo 3");
    }
};
}
```

This method is hooked up to a button. When I press it, I get this in the console:

```
<Info>: 23:41:52.226407 com.apple.AVConference: GKSConnSettings: set server: {
    "gk-cdx" = "17.173.254.218:4398";
    "gk-commnat-cohort" = "17.173.254.220:16386";
    "gk-commnat-main0" = "17.173.254.219:16384";
    "gk-commnat-main1" = "17.173.254.219:16385";
}
```

Only the third option is being printed out: Foo 3. I am going nuts here. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh!

I forgot that I had switched out bundle identifiers for temporary testing on my device.

You need to use the bundle identifier as specified in ITC.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason you might be seeing this even when your bundle ID is correct and you are sure everything is okay with your app info on iTunes Connect could be that you are logged into a real GameCenter account instead of a sandbox account. If so, log out of GameCenter by clicking on your email and selected to 'Sign Out' then log in to one of your test accounts (set up in iTunes Connect in the 'Manage Users' section). You'll have to accept the GameCenter Sandbox terms of service (it took a moment for these terms to appear for me so be patient). Once you have done so and have logged in with a sandbox account the GameCenter dialog should start showing up!